# Mounting errors in fstab while NAS is off

Tags: fstab, nfs

(Xubuntu 20.04) I am having problems with fstab getting through the mounting process when the NAS is off. When the NAS is on and I turn on the pc, I have no problem with the mounting. The fstab lines look like below. In Xubuntu 18.04 I made a script for mounting which I could start manually after the NAS is turned on. It works on Xubuntu 20.04 too. Thank you.

```
ip_nas:/folder  /mnt/folder nfs defaults    0   0
```

Comment: I do not use nfs. But have seen this: use autofs for any storage that isn't connected directly to the system with SAS, SATA, eSATA, or Infiniband connections
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Autofs Some have issues that fstab is processed before network is up. Example autofs and _netdev
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2450936

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this in /etc/fstab:

```
ip_nas:/folder  /mnt/folder nfs defaults    0   0
```

To this (this assumes that ip_nas is in your /etc/hosts file, else use IP address):

```
//ip_nas/folder  /mnt/folder nfs defaults,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=30    0   0
```

or

```
//192.168.x.x/folder  /mnt/folder nfs defaults,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=30    0   0
```

And see if that helps. Report back.

Comment: It thought it worked, but I had '#' before the line in fstab. It seems that your solution is not working.

Comment: In dmesg I am getting a lot of these lines "NFS4: Couldn't follow remote path", "FS-Cache: Duplicate cookie detected", "FS-Cache: O-cookie c=blabla fl=222 nc=0 na=1]" and "FS-Cache: O-cookie c=blabla fl=2 nc=0 na=1]", etc. After maybe 5 minutes it continues to boot.

Comment: @mevrouwtje So the line in fstab was commented out? How did it ever mount the NAS then? Show me your script, and tell me when/how you use it. Can you mount the NAS manually, or with your script?

Comment: @mevrouwtje See edit in my answer.

Comment: I always use 192.168.x.x. First I used "defaults" instead of "defaults,nofail,..". It worked/works when my NAS is on, but when my nas is off booting takes approximately 4 minutes and there are lots of errors in the dmesg. That is when I put # in front of the code. After that I changed the code according to your solution, but forgot to delete the #. That is why I thought your solution worked. Of course I tested it only with the NAS off.

Comment: @mevrouwtje Then use the last example in my answer. Remove your original line, as it's clearly incorrect. Then `sudo mount -a` with NAS on to assure that the new fstab line works. Then `umount` the NAS. Then `sudo mount -a` with the NAS off. (`nfs` **might** need to be `smb` or `cifs`).

Comment: As I already wrote to you I am always using 192.168.x.x (your third solution right?). I also already wrote you I never had problems with the NAS on, also not with your solution I assume.

Comment: @mevrouwtje I'm getting mixed information here. Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/fstab` and your manual mounting script.

Comment: Hopefully the question on top is more clearly now. The script that I run manually after I have turned the NAS on is: sudo mount 'ip_nas:/folder' /mnt/folder